# ASP.net 5 Beta 8 cannot install in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I currently have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I previously installed ASP.NET Beta 7 successfully using the same method I'm trying to install Beta 8.

I used the method described in this [BETA 8 install instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442).

> 1.Close all instances of Visual Studio.
>
> 2.Install .NET Version Manager (Beta8) using DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi. For 32 bit machines use DotNetVersionManager-x86.msi.
>
> 3.Update Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (Beta8) by installing WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi. If you are using Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web, then install WebToolsExtensionsVWD14.msi instead.

On the 3rd step when running the installer WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi I get the following error message

> This product requires visual studio 14". Please install Visual Studio
> 14 then try installing this product again"

When I open Visual Studio it does display I have version 14 installed

[screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/l57glxzrl/)

Then, I uninstalled Beta 7 by running the uninstaller and tried installing Beta 8 and I still got the error.

My question: How do I install ASP.NET Beta 8?

Comment: Do you have other versions of visual studio installed?

Comment: Yes I have Visual Studio 2013 Premium installed as well. I also tried restarting the machine and running the installers again after the restart but same problem. Next step is to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 and reinstall

Comment: Have you also tried removing VS 2013?

Comment: I have just uninstalled VS2015 Enterprise and installed VS2015 Professional and I get the exact same problem

Comment: Yes, but have you tried to uninstall VS2013?

Comment: I have uninstalled VS2013 as well and get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: You need to run the MSI package with Administrator privileges

I was able to install it by opening a command prompt window as Administrator and then run the msi directly.

Alternatively you can also add the "Run As Administrator" option to your right click options by changing your registry. [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/178826/how-to-force-an-msi-package-to-install-using-administrator-mode/)